# Can I Display User Specific Data throughout the site without adding to each view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a site (MVC5) with a partial that is a header. This header displays the users name, and a logo of the organisation that they represent.

Each page also has a ViewModel of page specific data.

Is there any way I can have this Partial rendered on each page from a common model / object behind the scenes, or do I need to add my 'userheader' viewmodel to the viewmodel on each page?

Comment: Isn't what default `_layout.cshtml` is for?

Comment: If I do that, and also (on certain pages) want to display some page specific information in the header, how can I access the ViewBag of a specific page. Or do I need a method on each controller to set up the header, and add in page specific information as required?

Comment: If you put your header in a _normal_ view with its own controller then you can render it in `_layout.cshtml` using `RenderAction()` instead of `Partial()`. Doing this you'll have initialization code only in one controller.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that. But say I have 2 pages, where I wish to display some additional text. The controller doesnt know which page has called its HeaderInformation method, so how do I add in that specific text on those pages?

Comment: Doesn't it? Controller method for a view rendered with `RenderAction()` can have parameters, you can add a `string additionalText` parameter to controller method (with a default empty value) and it'll make it available in model. Of course if you put `RenderAction()` in your shared layout file then you'll need more logic to decide _when_ you need additional text. If you decide to repeat `RenderAction()` in each view (probably inside a `@section header` then it'll go straight.

Comment: Thanks, its all sorted :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your requirement done through `ChildActionOnly`, lets say -

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoggedIn()
{
    // create your User View Model and pass it to Login Partial View
    return PartialView("_LoginPartial", user);
}
```

Now create a Partial View with a stringly typed model what you are returning from the controller action above.

And in your Layout you can get the partial view like shown below -

```
@Html.Action("LoggedIn", "ControllerName")
```

In this way there is no need for you to include the same models across different views.

Comment: +1 for ChildActionOnly, I didn't know about it. Not mandatory in usage but pretty safer to have!